# Using getCurrentFocus or getSystemService to get View doesn´t work?

Tags: java, android, inputmethodmanager

I want to hide the keyboard:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

if (view != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Now I have the problem, that `getCurrentFocus` and `getSystemService` are colored red and it says:

```
Cannot resolve method getCurrentFocus() / getSystemService()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `getSystemService` should have a `context` before:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); // or context
```

or `getActivity()` or similiar codes to get the context.

**Check out the codes:** [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)